# Autowire Bean and application.yml file in another jar file

Tags: spring-boot, maven, executable-jar

I am experimenting with spring boot multi module projects for my understanding.

My Over All Goal is :
1.Build Spring boot project as independent jar and utilise it on another project.
2.Autowire  Bean properties inside jar as per new project. Make it independent.

Things I have done so far.

Project **providerModule1**

1. Declare a Service(MyService).

   ```
    @Component
    public class MyService {

        @Autowired
        ServiceProperties serviceProperties;

        public String getInfoFromProperties() {
            return serviceProperties.toString();
        }
    }
   ```
2. Create a bean called **ServiceProperties** that will be used in to **MyService**.

   ```
    package com.demo.multimodule.providerModule1.util;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import lombok.Data;

    @Component
    @Data
    public class ServiceProperties {
        @Value("${default.userName}")
        private String name;

        @Value("${default.email}")
        private String email;

        @Value("${default.age}")
        private String age;
    }
   ```
3. Load the bean ServiceProperties by reading propeties from yml file.

   default:
   userName: userName1
   email: default@email.com
   age: 18
4. Build the Project ProviderModule1 using maven plugin

Project **ParentProjectApplication**
5. Load the maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.demo.multimodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>providerModule1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>app-to-import</classifier>
</dependency>
```

5. Autowire the  MyService from project providerModule1

   ```
    package com.multimodule.demo.parentProject.service;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import com.demo.multimodule.providerModule1.service.MyService;

    @Service
    public class HomeService {

        @Autowired
        private  MyService myService;

        public String getHomeInfo() {
            return "Home Info from Home service : "+myService.getInfoFromProperties();
        }
    }
   ```

   5. Initially myservice  was not getting loaded .Hence I added this step to main application class:

      ```
      @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.demo.multimodule.providerModule1.service",
                   "com.demo.multimodule.providerModule1.util"})
           public class ParentProjectApplication {
      ```

      }

**Question 1** : Is this the only way using which I can autowire bean from a jar. If there is another way let me know.

I executed the Project ParentProjectApplication and it seem to work as expected.

**Question 2** : Is it possible to autowire  **new yml property** from Project **ParentProjectApplication** and make **ServiceProperties** bean of project **ProviderModule1** utilise it.

Comment: 1. You can autowire your beans in counstructor, this alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

you can try spring.factory to create beans.
refer the link below

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html